# how to define a multidiscrete action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python-3.x, openai-gym

I want to define a Multi Discrete action space for Reinforcement Learning, gym style and Stable Baselines compatible (A2C, PPO) with the following structure :

```
entry : 'nothing', 'entry with SL 100', 'entry with SL 200', 'entry with SL 300'
hold : 'nothing'
close: 'nothing', 'partial', 'total'
```

how can I define it?

and how should I deal with received actions ex ,
if algo chooses entry he will tell entry[2] and will access the 'entry with SL 200' in loop and perform specified actions? or will tell ex [2,0,0] ?

thank you

update:
ok, already understood that it should be initialized as `'MultiDiscrete([ 4, 1, 3 ])'`

but how should I do the action function, should I do ex:

```
'received action' = [2,0,0]

if received action.shape(0) == 0:
 ...
elif received action.shape(0) == 1:
 needed funcs 
 ...
elif received action.shape(0) == 2:
 needed funcs 
 ...
 
 ...
elif received action.shape(2) == 0:
 ...
elif received action.shape(2) == 1:
 needed funcs 
 ...
```

thank you for your help !

update :

ok, already understood that i can get a sample of action space after initialize it with action_space.sample()

answer is closed thank you